# proper formatting and indent for nested enumerate

Tags: enumitem

I am trying a nested `enumerate` with

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lineno,enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=Phase \arabic*:]
    \item Hello World
          \begin{enumerate} [label*=\alph*.]
              \item Foo bar
          \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which is indented back and writing over the line number (see images),
[image: actual output]
Also don't want "Phase" in 2nd enumerate
I am looking for output like:

```
1  Phase 1: Hello world
2     1.a: Foo Bar
```

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the on-the-fly (re)definitions of level-1 and level-2 enumerated items from

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=Phase \arabic*:]
\begin{enumerate} [label*=\alph*.]
```

to

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=Phase \arabic*:,ref=\arabic*]
\begin{enumerate}[label=\theenumi.\alph*:]
```

---

You may also want to add the option `left=0pt` to the level-1 definition in order to avoid interference with the line numbers.

---

The updated MWE and associated output (the framelines denote the edges of the textblock):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 9in},showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lineno,enumitem}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\begin{enumerate}[label=Phase \arabic*:, ref=\arabic*, left=0pt]
    \item Hello World
          \begin{enumerate} [label=\theenumi.\alph*:]
              \item Foo bar
          \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: An additional comment: If you want the colons in the level-1 and level-2 "numbers" to be aligned vertically, be sure to add `left=-28pt` to the level-2 definition. (Be sure to suitably adjust the length depending on the font and font size of your document.)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it bit differently from Mico. I am using:

```
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1.5cm,label*=\bfseries Stage \arabic*:]
     \begin{enumerate} [leftmargin=0pt,label=\emph{\arabic{enumi}.\alph*}:]
```

I have upvoted mico. I am posting this for completeness.